# Ignore an element while building list in python

Tags: python, list, syntactic-sugar

I need to build a list from a string in python using the `[f(char) for char in string]` syntax and I would like to be able to ignore (not insert in the list) the values of f(x) which are equal to `None`.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

We could create a "subquery".

```
[r for r in (f(char) for char in string) if r is not None]
```

If you allow all False values (0, False, None, etc.) to be ignored as well, `filter` could be used:

```
filter(None, (f(char) for char in string) )
# or, using itertools.imap,
filter(None, imap(f, string))
```

Comment: I like the first one, thanks! Very clean to just build an iterable as the intermediate. I have been doing either two lines, or `[f(x) for x in l if f(x) is not None]`, unnecessarily performing the op twice.

Comment: @luke-davis, not realy if you use something called memoization. But it's still not elegance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a conditional in the for, to check of each element is not None or empty

```
[element for element in list_of_elements) if element]
```

this allow to avoid a double looping

Example. Remove even numbers from a list:

```
f = lambda x: x % 2
list_of_elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 34, 45, 55, 65, 66]
c = [element for element in list_of_elements if f(element)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 45, 55, 65]
```

Comment: This is not really what this question was about. I want(ed) to remove elements from a list *after* some transformation `f` was applied, based on the result of the transformation, but without having to call the transform function `f` twice on very element. Your solution does not answer that. And is not syntactically valid either.

Comment: Since this is all using iterators, there is no "double looping" involved in the accepted answer.

Comment: There are two nested for loops in the above answer. I added an example